# Run AppAndroid on tablet and mobile phone support multi screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablet-layout

i need that my app Android will be supported by 2 devices phone  and tablet .

i can find library to integer in my app and supported all screen size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to support multiple screen sizes for your app. You can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) guide from Android Developers. Tl;dr you should make your layouts as flexible as possible. That includes but not limited to

1. Use ConstraintLayout to define the percentage of screen covered by a component, ratio of sizes etc etc
2. Avoid using hardcoded values(like layout_width="100dp" etc)

Also for a tablet, you must design an alternative layout which can take advantage of the larger screen in landscape mode